# Swift 3 URLSession Error "Cannot invoke 'URLSession' with an argument list of type '(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration)'"

Tags: ios, json, swift2, swift3

I am updating a Swift 2.2 project to Swift 3, and receive the following error on the line 'let session = URLSession(configuration: config)':

> > Cannot invoke 'URLSession' with an argument list of type '(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration)'

This is my code:

```
    let urlPath: String = "http://iosquiz.com/service.php"
    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)



    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL)

    task.resume()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That code compiles without problems in  my Swift 3 project.

Comment: What imports do you have in your file? Are you importing foundation and/or UIKit?

Comment: @DuncanC I have imported both foundation and UIKit

Comment: I solved the error by adding "Foundation" to the line 'let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: config)'. Not sure why I had to do this considering I already imported Foundation (maybe it just wanted me to specify that I was using Foundation in that instance), but it worked anyways. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TeddyMurtagh you only need to import UIKit